# Embedding Instance of LibreOffice into Application (with TOLEContainer)

Tags: delphi, com, ole, libreoffice, delphi-xe4

I am trying to embed an instance of LibreOffice with Delphi in my Application. My main goal is it to achieve a result like in MS office when im embedding LibreOffice documents into it. If possible, i want to use TOLEConatiner to achieve this.

For testing i wrote a program with a TOleContainer Component:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog.Execute then
  if FileExists(OpenDialog.FileName) then
    OleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName, false)
end;
```

For MS Office (opening a .docx-file), this already works without problems. Opening an .odt-file and then activating the OLEContainer results in an empty frame, showing more or less nothing, therefore not viewable or editable.

So i tried to find out more about LibreOffice, OLE and COM. I have found out that i can use OO API to access its functionality , I first need to create an OLEObject of the OO ServiceManager, then creating a desktop service to create a document, something like this:

```
Server := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
Desktop := Server.CreateInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop')
LoadParams := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
Param := Server.Bridge_GetStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue');
Param.Name := 'Hidden';
Param.Value := True;
LoadParams[0] := Param;
Document := Desktop.LoadComponentFromURL('private:factory/swriter', '_default', 0, LoadParams);
```

My problem is that i don't see how to combine this with OLEContainer to get my expected result. Examples I have found (for example [this one](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=47644)) couldn't really help me either as they open a seperate instance of LibreOffice. I also informed myself about some services of LibreOffice to find any solution, but its quite hard for me to get through the documentation.

OLE, COM and LibreOffice API is a new topic for me and i feel quite lost there. So i come up with the following question:

Is it even possible to show and edit a document in a LibreOffice instance embedded in an OleContainer?
If yes, how can i achieve that?
If no, are there any alternatives to show a LibreOffice Instance in my application?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is even possible?

Comment: As ive mentioned, MSOffice already uses this functionality and it works there (and i expect MSOffice uses TOleContainer too). But i could not find anything about how that is done.

Comment: I don't see where office comes into this. You are using libre office. Can it be embedded?

Comment: That is actually my question. LibreOffice can be embedded into MSOffice (and into itself as well) and it seems they are both using TOLeConatiner. So I am trying to embed LibreOffice into an OLEContainer in Delphi. However, i am not sure whether this is the answer you expected. What is your point?

Comment: That's all I was trying to ascertain, whether or not it was even possible to embed using OLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a while ago, but i have found the reason for the empty frame in the container:

While working with MSOffice, the method `DoVerb` internally calls `IOleDocumentSite.ActivateMe` of `TOleContainer` which sets different attributes, including `FDocObj`. For LibreOffice, the interface `IOleDocumentSite` does not seem to be supported (`QueryInterface` raises an error), therefore `ActivateMe` is never called. This results in not setting `FDocObj`, therefore receiving a wrong handle in `TOleContainer.GetWindow` (instead of OleContainer's own handle its parent's handle is received), and the document is not shown in the Container.

To solve the problem, I have set `FDocObj` to True before calling `DoVerb`. This might not be the final solution as i still dont understand completely how TOleContainer exactly works but for the moment this solution works for me.